# Javascript function which is not working

Tags: javascript

Im learning javascript and run into this problem where I want to combine objects and functions. I have the following which, according to me, should lead to 65 - the age I inserted. I get nothing however.

Any thoughts on what Im doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function person(name, age) {

this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft;


}


function yearsLeft {

var numYears = 65 - this.age;
return numYears;

}

var Marc = new person("Marc", 23);
document.write(Marc.yearsUntilRetire());



</script>
```

Comment: Tip: Add the function to the person prototype for improved performance when creating multiple instances

Comment: The casing of your variable names should be backwards: `var marc = new Person()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot () in the yearsLeft declaration!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function person(name, age) {

this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft;


}


function yearsLeft() {

var numYears = 65 - this.age;
return numYears;

}

var Marc = new person("Marc", 23);
document.write(Marc.yearsUntilRetire());
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing parenthesis in the function declaration :

```
function yearsLeft() {
```

To fix this kind of errors, you must look at the errors in the console. The line where the syntax error happens is shown.

Recommended reading : [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Answer (score 0):

There could be two errors, if you look at your console, it could be that you are missing `()` immediately after `yearsleft` function declaration. and you are trying to write out `Marc.yearsUntilRetire()` instead of `Marc.yearsUntilRetire`. I think `yearsUntilRetire` is a variable that takes the number of years returned from `yearsLeft` and not a function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function person(name, age) {

this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft;


}


function yearsLeft {

var numYears = 65 - this.age;
return numYears;

}

var Marc = new person("Marc", 23);
document.write(Marc.yearsUntilRetire());



</script>
```